# Errors building gradle w/ protobufs in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've been messing around in Java for awhile, but this is the first time I'm doing anything with Gradle, Protobufs, and gRPC so I'm having some information overload right now.

I'm trying to run this through IntellJ on my Windows 10 machine.

https://github.com/tronprotocol/java-tron

I follow their instructions,

`Clone java-tron
set gradle to auto-import in intellij
enable annotations`

then I run build and I'm getting these errors and I can't figure out why. I'm not getting any of the auto-generated code and I'm stuck. The platform is so new that there's very little documentation, so I'm hoping someone here might know enough to point me in the right direction.. Thanks

Here is what I'm gettting when the build fails.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAtO6.jpg

Comment: Could you re-run the failed test and add the logs there? In your picture there is no clue of what could be wrong :(

Comment: @Luc Thanks for responding, I'm still struggling with this so I just cleared my logs and did a fresh install from forking the repo to the gradle build that fails. Thanks for looking at least, I hope it can help me get this running 

[Logs](https://pastebin.com/neLtWhKi)

Comment: What do the report say? C:/Git/java-tron/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

Comment: @Luc Here is all the info from the report.

[Report Info](https://imgur.com/a/il4J4Cv)

Answer (score 0):

Reading at your log I can see that you have two exceptions: one is thrown by the code NoSuchElementException, and another one is thrown when the server is disconnected.

You have two failing tests:
https://github.com/tronprotocol/java-tron/blob/develop/src/test/java/org/tron/core/net/node/StartFetchSyncBlockTest.java

and
https://github.com/tronprotocol/java-tron/blob/develop/src/test/java/org/tron/core/witness/WitnessControllerTest.java

To fix this I would start by investigate why you got disconnected during your test. You could add some custom log in your class to understand exactly what is going on there.